# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No valid combination of account information found - Tried to edit conn string, but did not work

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I created new java based Function with QueueTrigger.(plan to change to TopicTrigger) I made no change and debugged with error in local env. What could be issue?  If this is related to Storage for webjob, I do have "AzureWebJobsStorage" definitions on local.settings.json. I do not know if this function use it or not.

"AzureWebJobsStorage" is in format of  "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myjavafunctionappstorage;AccountKey=12345UyBcsN456ouBMPkmZs+hagTjEkdrJ3xM3TzQDp7U9OoFJYlEsV9NQeF0E0MVK9EevPtKpqY+DblPOMQQ==;",

```
[20.3.2020 13.04.39] The 'TopicTriggerCosmosOutput' function is in error: 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.TopicTriggerCosmosOutput'. 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No valid combination of account information found.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I test local with my connection string, the problem is your connection format. If you use the storage queue trigger function, the `connection` value should be `AzureWebJobsStorage` key in your local.settings.json. And looks like you set the service bus connection string `queueconstring`.

And if you are using service bus trigger function, please refer to this doc:[Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=java), the binding should be `ServiceBusQueueTrigger` not the `QueueTrigger`.

Comment: using ServiceBusQueueTrigger fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with your format, usually I get the value of AzureWebJobsStorage from here:

[image]

Its format should look like this:

DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=yourstoragename;AccountKey=xxxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net